# add image as a border

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins

I have a image which i call as `user_image` and i have another image which i call `border_image`.

I want to do the functionality like when i click `border_image` (*Cars2_h.gif*)  it should appear like a border for `user_image` (*flowers.jpeg*).

Right now my old team members have done that in java with image rendering and i was not sure about how they did that.

I want to do the same functionality in ruby (moving to **Ruby On Rails**). I need help from you guys very badly.

I tried using `mini_magick` composite method, but its not working as I expected.

Comment: Please supply some code, preferably as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, this is much easier done client side in CSS. use the CSS background attribute to define the border image, assign to a CSS class and then on click just toggle the CSS class for the main image. provide padding around it so that the background is visible and that's it. Here's some pseude code, I've created a JSFiddle for you where you can see it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/RK8CD/

HTML

```
<button id="toggle">toggle background</button> 
<img id="user_image" src=".....">
```

CSS

```
.withBackground { 
   background: url('....') repeat;
   padding:20px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#user_image').toggleClass("withBackground");
});
```

if you want to use multiple images as backgrounds and let the user choose, then perhaps it's better to set the CSS attribute directly instead of making a separate class for each image.